# how to get Body raw JSON data from Postman to Java

Tags: java, json, api, servlets, postman

I have the variable customer-id and a value in the raw data in JSON format. I want to get the value from postman to java. How can I implement it?

[image]

Comment: From Postman to Java? You mean from the Endpoint that Postman calls to Java?

Comment: Firstly, use some http library, for example: http://unirest.io/java.html. Secondly, take a look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json - this will help you with JSON objects

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to use Postman in Java.

But you can do the same thing using Java.

First, you should call the same endpoint that Postman calls. You can use [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html) to access this endpoint.

```
Unirest.post("http://api.callme.com/json")
    .asJson()
```

It is good to observe the METHOD that is called on Postman and use the same on Unirest. In the code above, I'm using the method POST.

Then, you will get a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

**try this code
 THis is a basic code to get the data from json data and please search**

Download this jar file [json](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm)

How to add jar file documentation [here](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44)

[HttpURLconnection](https://www.journaldev.com/7148/java-httpurlconnection-example-java-http-request-get-post)

```
 String url = "http//url"; //define the url here
    URL obj; //making the object 
    obj = new URL(url);         
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

**//add authorisation if you have any**

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "UTF-8");
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
String nid = jsonObject.get("customer-id").toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should have to set content type to **application/json**. And in your java web application side, you can fetch that json from request. If you are using servlet then you have to use `request.getParameter("customer-id");`